# SQL Left Join, Cross Join - Find a Missing Value

Tags: t-sql

This should be really easy, but I just can't spot the answer (I'll blame it on the fact that I've been SQL coding for almost 14 hours now).

I have a table called report with a "Label" field and a "ReportYear" field. I know that I have three possible "Label" values, but not every label will have an entry for every year.

I can select a distinct label list and I get:

```
'Regular'
'Special'
'None'
```

Doing some manual data selection here, I know that 2011 and 2010 have 0 entries with the label 'Special', but I need a query to pull this information together, so that it comes out:

```
'Regular' - '2012' - '5'
'Regular' - '2011' - '2'
'Regular' - '2010' - '1'
'Special' - '2012' - '3'
'Special' - '2011' - '0'
'Special' - '2010' - '0'
'None' - '2012' - '10'
'None' - '2011' - '5'
'None' - '2010' - '2'
```

Hopefully that makes sense.

I know I can `SELECT Count(*), Label FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Label FROM Report) t1` ... but then? `LEFT JOIN Report t2 ON t1.Label=t2.Label`? `CROSS JOIN`?

My brain is fried.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
   L.Label,
   Y.ReportYear,
   ReportCount = Count(R.Label)
FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT Label FROM dbo.Report) L
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ReportYear FROM dbo.Report) Y
   LEFT JOIN dbo.Report R
      ON L.Label = R.Label
      AND Y.ReportYear = R.ReportYear
GROUP BY
   L.Label,
   Y.ReportYear
```

Now, this isn't really ideal because you're doing an entire table scan, twice, just to get the labels and years.

Unless I am misunderstanding things, it seems to me that you should normalize the `Report` table so it has a `ReportLabelID` column and then have a `ReportLabel` table with the distinct labels. Then you can put the `ReportLabel` table in place of the `DISTINCT` query above.

And you can also eliminate the `ReportYear` subquery by parameterizing the whole query to accept `BeginYear` and `EndYear` or something like that. Or, you could get the `Min(ReportYear), Max(ReportYear)` from the table, and assuming you have an index on the column it may be able to turn it into seeks (two separate queries might be needed to get this), then use a numbers table or on-the-fly numbers table to generate the sequence of years between them.

Once you make those two changes, the query will then perform significantly better.